# How to convert this Query into ORACLE command

Tags: oracle

How to write

```
IFF(ISNULL(PARNT_TOUR_PCKG), 'VOI', 'TRIAL') = TOUR_TP.SRC_RFRNC_ID
```

In Oracle

Comment: Shouldn't it be `IIF`?

Answer (score 0):

try this in where clause

```
CASE WHEN PARNT_TOUR_PCKG IS NULL THEN  'VOI' ELSE 'TRIAL' END = TOUR_TP.SRC_RFRNC_ID
```

Comment: THANKS CAN WE USE COALESCE(PARNT_TOUR_PCKG,'VOI','TRIAL')?

Comment: NO YOU CANT because PARNT_TOUR_PCKG is null then it equas 'VOI' ,if it is not null  it equels PARNT_TOUR_PCKG.

Comment: WRITING ALL UPPERCASE IS CONSIDERED SHOUTING AND RUDE. Please don't do it

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar - I think the advice was aimed at the OP not you

Answer (score 0):

You may use `NVL2()` in Oracle

```
WHERE NVL2(PARNT_TOUR_PCKG,'TRIAL', 'VOI')  = TOUR_TP.SRC_RFRNC_ID
```

*`NVL2( string1, value_if_not_null, value_if_null )`*

Comment: Personally I like `nvl2()` because it's less typing and after twenty years I can remember which argument substitutes for `not null` and which for `null`. However, `CASE()` is the industry standard and clearer, so that is probably the better solution.